# Problems with integrating google calender

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vb.net, google-calendar-api

i am facing so much of confusions and problems while migrating from google api v2 over to v3.

I am dealing with the job scheduling of each employees in a company with the help of integrated google calender. i lost the full control while the provider change the version. let me know the following thing?

1. can i access the calender of an employee if his/her gmail id and its password is known?
2. is it needed to provide individual CLIENT ID and CLIENT secret?
3. what is the use of public Public API access(server key)
4. how to form the request url that must send to the server.
5. how to use the JSON file downloaded from the developer console
6. previously i was using the query as

   ```
   Try
      Dim myService As New CalendarService("test")
      myService.setUserCredentials(user_name, user_password)
      Dim query As New CalendarQuery()
      query.Uri = New Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full")
     Dim resultFeed As CalendarFeed = DirectCast(myService.Query(query), CalendarFeed)
   Catch ex As Exception
     lblerror.Text = ex.ToString 
     connect = 0
   End Try
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I access the calendar of an employee if his/her gmail id and its password is known?

   - no you must use Oauth2  [Google Calendar Authentication](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)
2. Is it needed to provide individual CLIENT ID and CLIENT secret?

   - No client_id and Client secret identify your project to Google you only need one.
3. what is the use of public Public API access(server key)

   - This is for public apis like Google Books API that do not require authentication.
4. how to form the request url that must send to the server.

   - I recommend you look into using the Google-api-dotnet-client lib it will handle all that for 
     you. [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)
5. how to use the JSON file downloaded from the developer console

   - you don't really need to use it if you use the client lib it just contains the same data as you already asked about open it and see
6. previously i was using the query as

   - That is VB code I think and not C# that's not how you will be doing it now.  I recommend you start by reading [Google Calendar API Authentication with C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/)

Comment: Then what is the use of JSON file that are downloaded from the developer console? +1 for you

Comment: It contains the client id and secret depend upon how you  code your authentication you can either set it to read it from the file or put the values in variables yourself.

Comment: One could probably argue that in a web application it might be best to have it in the file store the file in a secure location on the server out side of the web root.  But I am not the best to discuss web security with.  I normally do installed applications and just have it coded in variables. :)

Comment: first point is not clear enough, can you please explain it more? i collect the client information and relevent data from the developer console, now can i access other employee's calender information using my reference?

Comment: That is to much to go into hear and not really part of this question. If you want to know how to get it all working I sugest you read this tutorial.  http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/  there is a sample project on github as well.